# ArgoCDO CLI get details of resources?

Tags: argocd

I am using **ArgoCD CLI** to access ArgoCD and watch/manage my K8s clusters.

**How can I get details on some resources like events?**

I know, I can list the resources with `argocd app resources <app-name>`.

But how can I get the details I can get in the web-app like here?

[image]

I need to debug eg. why a container fails to start:
[image]

*Please note: yes, I know how to use kubectl, but I don't have permissions on all clusters to use kubectl and need to access the logs and events with ArgoCD. Hence the question.*

Answer (score 0):

These are actually the events from the resources themselves. You can run
`kubectl describe <resource_type> <resource_name>` and you will see the events on the bottom.

Comment: Thank you, but sorry, I can't. I don't have access with kubectl and can only use argocd. That's why I am asking. My only way is to access the events and logs with argocd, but I would like to use the CLI for scripting some things.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I couldn't find a way to do it with argocd cli but if you open the web ui in the browser and look in the developer tools you can see what the rest requests the ui does to get the events and make these http calls from your script. For example this is the endpoint which returns the events. `your-argo.com/api/v1/applications/onepassword-connect-prd/events`.
you have to make several requests. Look in the developer tools to map the full flow.

Comment: Of course, this would be an option. But I would prefer to use a CLI instead of develop a CLI 

Comment: @Datz did you find a solution how to get the events through the CLI? I'm in the same scenario

Comment: @NicolasZawada sorry, not yet